# Driving on Tikz in Texmaker

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

My LaTex distribution is MikTeX 2.9 and I am using TeXmaker.
The LaTeX has been installed successfully and I have the deserving output for such test:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Matinking
\begin{equation}
    \phi + \psi = \chi
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But the problem is that there is no `TikZ` library within my distribution as I check the `package Manager (Admin)`... Even after the trying to find new updates, there is no `TikZ` among the offers.

I just tried to add `\usepackage{tikz}` to above code but a message box containing below error will be appeared:

```
The file required: tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty is missing. It is part of the following packege: ms
```

The odd thing is that there is even no `ms` package among update offers!

How would I handle this?!...

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error looks strange.  However the bundle might be named after `pgf` rather than `tikz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird error just resolved by re-installing some packages:

```
ms + xcolor + mptopdf
```

Actually, update was not a cure for the problem, but the re-installing above target packages, could which be taken as prerequisites of `TikZ` into account, removed the issue.

Now calling `\usepackage{tikz}` is possible, safely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed the basic package of MiKTeX. You have to integrate the package that miss with the integrated package manager. I don't use MiKTeX, but at this site I fond that.

http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html

Good work.

Comment: No... That is one with the complete set of the packages... But the issue was from the other side, as I mentioned in the response...