# Add the tickz package for TexMaker

Tags: texmaker

I'm trying to use the tickz package with TexMaker:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tickz}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\begin{document}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile with the `F1` key, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tickz.sty' not found.
```

I already tried the following:

- [How to add new packages to Texmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125918/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texmaker#130303) but running `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` didn't fix it
- [Driving on Tikz in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245734/driving-on-tikz-in-texmaker) but I don't understand how to reinstall "ms + xcolor + mptopdf"
- [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz) which leads to [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) but when I run `tlmgr update --all`, I get the following error:

  ```
  (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
  cannot setup TLPDB in /home/username/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
  ```

Comment: You should use `tikz`, not `tickz`.

Comment: There is no 'c' in `tikz`.  Maybe turn off auto-correct in your editor. :)

Comment: ... and a lonely `\end{picture}` doesn't make sense either. Use `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` instead.

Comment: Replacing "tickz" with "tikz" fixed it! The mistake about the missing begins and ends comes from a mistake while copying and pasting for the minimal example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a trivial misspelling and solved in the comments.